# Col width in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

In react one can set col widths depending on the screen size:

```
<Col xs={12} sm={4} md={4} lg={4}>
```

The problem I am having is that My Parent component is rendering two child components side by side, A and B. 
A is a table that holds other components in every table cell, Child1, Child2 etc..

How can I define `<Col>` widths for Child1 based on my parent A width and not the screen width?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Col widths depend on the width of the parent by default, for example

```
<Col xs={6}>
  <Col xs={6}>
    A
  </Col>
  <Col xs={6}>
    A
  </Col>
</Col>    
<Col xs={6}>
  <Col xs={6}>
    B
  </Col>
  <Col xs={6}>
    B
  </Col>
</Col>
```

will result in

```
A    A    B    B
```

Please post your code and the result you're getting to help us find the problem.

Comment: Col widths do not depend on width of parent by default. According to the documentation: `The number of columns you wish to span

for Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

class-prefix col-xs-`

Comment: That is bootstraps way of giving you more control over your responsive design..that is, if you use `<Col xs={6} md={4} lg={2} />`, then it will render in half the parent's width in a small screen(xs), a third of the parent's width in a medium screen(md) and so on. But it will depend on the parent's width and not on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`Col` should not be parent or child of `Col`.

If I wanted to do like your picture I would do like this:

```
<Row>

  <Col size={4}>
    <Row> A
      <Col size={12}> Child 1 </Col>
      ...
    </Row> 
  </Col>

  <Col>
    <Row> B ... </Row>

</Row>
```

`size={4}` = should be translated to `col-4` but I can't find that in react-bootstrap (therefore you might have to set each viewport's size: xs, sm, md, etc...)

`col-12` of course implies the whole row in a 12-column setup (like standard Bootstrap)

Comment: `<div class="w-100"></div>` can also be used instead of col-12 to make a new row.